# About ordering of method IndexBatch.New(actions)

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have a question regarding to Index batch operation descripted here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-import-data-dotnet

In the sample as:
[Sample in the document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HhsZ.png)

These 3 items are different documents identified by field of hotel Id.

My question is:

- what will happen if multiple actions against the same document (like specify the same hotel Id in the example) included in the array?
- How the index batch operation handle the ordering for the multiple actions against a same document?
- I understand for upload it makes sense to ensure distinct document Ids in the operation list, while this does not apply for merge.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Tony,

Azure Search provides no guarantees about the order of operations in an index batch operation. They are all executed independently, so it's possible to have a partial success. Please see [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents#response) for more information about the response codes you can receive from this operation. I would avoid including multiple operations against the same document in a single batch.

Matt

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding for your question, I think you want to know more details about the concurrency of Index batch operation on the same document. Just per my experience, there are some thought shared for you as below.

1. Azure only opens its documents of REST APIs for different services and the related SDK sources for different programming languages, but the function-realizing mechanism of these services which we don't know directly.
2. Azure SDKs almost wrap Azure REST APIs using different programming languages. So we can speculate some mechanism via researching the usage of REST APIs.
3. The index batch operation is based on the REST API [Add, Update or Delete Documents (Azure Search Service REST API)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents), which handles multiple actions described in a single HTTP request that do these one by one. For multiple actions against the same document included in an array, there is no conflict in a single request because of synchronization.
4. If concurrently do many requests for the same document, there is some errors defined in the service which be introduced in the REST API document as below and will do necessary retryable operation.
   [image]

Hope it helps.